# How to set opacity to png image with transparent background using Magick++

Tags: c++, magick++

I'm using ImageMagick to render images.
I open [png file](http://fs42.www.ex.ua/show/999299911111/168912026/168912026.png) as Magick::Image and draw it on another Magick::Image and set opacity to png image. And save it as [jpg file](http://fs42.www.ex.ua/show/999299911111/168912034/168912034.jpg).

In saved file transparent background becomes black.

Example code:

```
    Image newImage;
    newImage.size(Geometry(1000, 1000));
    newImage.fillColor(Color(50, TransparentOpacity / 2, 50));
    newImage.draw(DrawableRectangle(0, 0, 1000, 1000));

    Image originalImage("test-Image-1.png");
    originalImage.opacity(TransparentOpacity / 2);
    newImage.composite( originalImage, 300, 100, AtopCompositeOp );

    newImage.magick("JPG");
    newImage.write("testImage3.jpg");
```

Is it possible to set transparency 50% to image and full transparent for background?

Comment: Are you sure the background is black, not transparent? How are you determining this? Perhaps your viewer simply chose black to present the "backdrop"? Provide all these details to (potentially) make this into a good question.

Comment: Jpeg doesn't support transparency. The matte color will default to black.

Comment: @emcconville If I'll save newImage in png format, result will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the line:

```cpp
originalImage.opacity(TransparentOpacity / 2);
```

The source, "test-Image-1.png", has an alpha-channel that looks like...

[image: Orignal alpha channel]

When you set opacity to 50%, you're setting the whole channel, not reducing the level by 50%. The alpha-channel altered with `originalImage.opacity` now looks looks like this...

[image: 50% alpha-channel]

There are many ways to alter the alpha-channel to *reduce* the image opacity. [Pixel iteration](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Pixels.html), [FX](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#diy_levels), and [level color](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#level-colors) to name a few. I'm a fan of isolating the alpha channel, altering the levels, and coping the channel back to the image. The example below simply "swaps" color values as 50% opacity == `gray50`.

```cpp
Image originalImage("test-Image-1.png");
Image mask(originalImage); // Clone image
mask.channel(OpacityChannel); // Isolate alpha-channel
/*
  For this example I'll mimic CLI options:
  "-fuzz 50% -fill gray50 -opaque black"
*/
mask.colorFuzz(MaxRGB * 0.5);
mask.opaque(Color("black"), Color("gray50"));
mask.negate();
// Copy mask image as new alpha-channel
originalImage.composite( mask, 0, 0, CopyOpacityCompositeOp );
```

[image: Reduced opacity by 50%]

Now you can composite over another image without worry of black background.